# ElasticSearch Java / Groovy API: how can I send JSON requests

Tags: java, rest, groovy, elasticsearch

Is it possible not to use custom API but simply send JSON request and recieve JSON response (use REST api)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So by saying "is it possible not to use custom API", you mean you don't want to use something like [HttpBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/), you just want to use raw groovy?

If you're only doing GETs, you can just us the [URL class](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/net/URL.html) and it's `text` method, and manually parse the JSON, but that is very limited.

If you need to do POST/PUT/DELETE/HEAD/etc, you're probably better off using something like HttpBuilder.  If that's not an option, you're left with implementing a subset of what HttpBuilder or HttpClient performs.